# Metal color representation issues (with sRGB pixel format)

Tags: ios, shader, metal, alphablending, metalkit

I can't achieve correct color representation in my very basic Metal-project if its CAMetalLayer `pixelFormat` is setted to `rgba8Unorm_srgb`. By correct I mean that my UIColor's and UIImage's should appear the same in Metal like in UIKit. I have find out that it's exactly that if my CAMetalLayer pixelFormat is `rgba8Unorm`. But I really need to use `rgba8Unorm_srgb`.

I've attached two screenshot of this project. It has a squared CAMetalLayer. It's gray background color is its `MTLRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)`. It also have white and black quads and one another quad with red gradient above them, which actually uses standard alpha blending:

```
colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add

colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha

colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

The only difference between the two screenshots is their CAMetalLayer pixelFormat. But as you can see even the clear color is already different. (They actually different exactly by the gamma-correction). White and black are the same, but all the other colors are different too. Alpha blending does't work correctly too on `rgba8Unorm_srgb`: you can see, that its half on the white destination is desaturated, and it half on the black destination is oversaturated.

From my understanding I don't need to worry about gamma-correction, don't need to modify my shaders or colors. Metal should do all the math in linear space regardless of pixelFormat. So why is that happening?

[image: rgba8Unorm]
[image: rgba8Unorm_srgb]

Comment: Could you create a test case that simply renders the pixels from a known buffer of values and then captures the output? Compare the original to the resulting output without any of the alpha blending should indicate if your logic is dealing with pixel formats correctly without having to also have alpha stuff in the equation.